# Is there a way to connect a new AWS ApiGateway to existing lambda funtion using AWS-CDK? (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am new to AWS CDK. I am trying to create a API gateway, and connect it to the AWS lambda. But I want these 2 modules to be separate code structures.

I created the lambda functions and the API gateway in 2 different projects. And my AWS console has both API and lambda init. But I am not sure how to connect my API gateway to these lambdas.

The only way I could find was

```
    new lambda.Function(this, 'createPr', {
      code: lambda.Code.asset("resources/lambdas"),
      ....
      ....
    });
```

But this required the directory structure pointing towards lambda code.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the other lambda function from ARN

```js
const otherFunction = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this, 'otherfunction', cdk.Fn.importValue("otherstack-function-arn"))
```

The cdk.Fn.importValue allow you to import value from other cloudformation script